In Antd how do I implement routes, for Sub menu and even for the Main menu title?
Example, If there is a side menu bar,
Activity
    - Screenshots
    - Apps
    - URls

Here the activity is the main menu title, i want route link for even this and then eve for screenshots, apps and urls
<Menu.SubMenu title="Activity" icon={<BsGraphUp style={{ fontSize: '22px', color: 'gray', fontWeight: 'bold' }} />}>
              <Menu.Item key="activity">
                <Link to='/activity'><span style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: '#31363F' }}>Activity</span></Link>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>Screenshots</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>Apps</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>Urls</Menu.Item>
            </Menu.SubMenu>

I tries this, but here there is no route for the main title
